# Make Chrome's menu more compact (vertically) in macOS

Tags: macos, google-chrome

Desktop real estate is very important to me. Chrome is large and sometimes takes up too much space. Sometimes, I want two windows (one on top of the other), but they are just too clunky because of of the menu/UI. Here's an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrFL4.png) of what I'm talking about.

IS there a way to make this smaller? I've looked up some themes, but I don't think they change it. I've also seen this solution: https://www.howtogeek.com/278699/how-do-you-adjust-google-chromes-ui-scaling/ but it's for windows.

Any ideas?

Comment: What were the Windows suggestions and why do they not work for Mac?

Comment: They were windows-specific commands/solutions using windows DPI scaling. I have no idea how to do that on mac. Mac does not have the same terminal system nor does it have the same properties tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Only solution I can think of is going to

> chrome://flags/#top-chrome-md

and choosing Normal - this switches Chrome to pre-MD2 design.
Consider using Safari, it's much more compact vertically.